# How to increase record and play volume with Java sound?

Tags: java, audio

I use the following code to record and play sounds with Java, but the volume is too low, how to make it louder, at least 2,3 times louder ?

```
public void Record_Audio(String File_Path,AudioFileFormat.Type File_Type)
{
  try
  {
    audioFormat=getAudioFormat();                        // Get things set up for capture
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo=new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,audioFormat);
    targetDataLine=(TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

    //Create a thread to capture the microphone data into an audio file and start the thread running. It will run 
    // until the Stop button is clicked. This method will return after starting the thread.
    new Record_Thread(File_Path,File_Type).start();
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}

private void Play_Audio_Recording()
{
  File Audio_File=new File(Current_Folder_Path+File_Name_ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()+"."+Get_Audio_File_Type());

  try
  {
    Audio_Clip=Applet.newAudioClip(Audio_File.toURI().toURL());
    Audio_Clip.play();
  }
  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

  class Record_Thread extends Thread
  {
    String File_Path;
    AudioFileFormat.Type File_Type;

    Record_Thread(String File_Path) { this(File_Path,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE); }

    Record_Thread(String File_Path,AudioFileFormat.Type File_Type)
    {
      this.File_Path=File_Path;
      this.File_Type=File_Type;
    }

    public void run()
    {
      Audio_File=new File(File_Path);

      try
      {
        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();
        AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine),File_Type,Audio_File);
      }
      catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the FloatControl.Type (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.Type.html) to set either the volume or the master gain. Something like:

```
targetDataLine=(TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl c = (FloatControl)targetDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
c.setValue(c.getMaximum());
```

might work.

Comment: I tried this, got error, there is no "c.getMaximum()" method.

Comment: Try that: needed to cast the control to the right type (FloatControl).

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Volume
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractLine.getControl(AbstractLine.java:150)

Comment: Odd. Is that for the record or the playback? Maybe try `FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN`.

Comment: That is for recording. I just tried again, got this : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Master Gain

Comment: What does Record_Thread do? Are you accessing the controls AFTER the target data line has been opened?

Comment: I just added Record_Thread into my question. I accessed the controls before calling the Record_Thread.

Comment: Ah, you typically have to open the line/clip before accessing the controls. I'd try `targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);` and then try adjusting the volume or master gain.